# Trying to fix - segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm executing a method to replace all spaces in a string with "%20". One may assume that the string has sufficient space at the end to hold the additional characters, and that one are given the "true" length of the string.

EXAMPLE:

Input: "Mr John Smith   ", 13

Output: "Mr%20John%20Smith"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void URL(char str[], int length)
{

    int spacecount = 0, index;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            spacecount++;
        }
    }
    index = length + spacecount * 2;
    if (length < strlen(str))
        str[length] = '\0';

    for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (str[j] == ' ')
        {
            str[index - 1] = '0';
            str[index - 2] = '2';
            str[index - 3] = '%';
            index = index - 3;
        }
        else
        {
            str[index - 1] = str[j];
            index--;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", str);
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int len;
    printf("Enter the string : ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("Enter the length : ");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    URL(str, len);
}
```

On executing the above code using gcc compiler, I'm getting the segmentation fault. I understand, what is segmentation fault. I want to fix it in this program.

Comment: `for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j++)` this goes forever, didnt you meant `j--` ?

Comment: I assume the segfault occurs here: `str[length] = '\0'`, you need to allocate a new chunk: `char newstr[index + 1]` and then use `newstr` instead of `str`

Comment: I'm need to solve this operation in place

Comment: Do you use a debugger and execute line by line?

Comment: There is no chance to replace the spaces inplace, the original length is not big enough, in languages like java or pyhon you get `IndexOutOfBoundException` (or similar), C does not control it, but it does not mean that you can go outside of the array with no consequences

Comment: @neshkeev It can be done in place.

Comment: The original length is counted till last letter of "smith", which makes it 13 but if I give spaces after "smith" to replace %20. it can be taken as inplace.

Comment: @4386427 I presume you are working on the answer, I would love to learn the in place solution from it

Comment: @neshkeev Well, the posted function does the job - at least when the input is correct

Comment: @neshkeev See answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

work?

What will `str` contain if your input is: `Mr John Smith`

It's not doing what you think! The answer is that it will contain `Mr` and thereby you don't have a string of length 13.

Use `fgets` instead but remember to remove the newline.

The complete program could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void URL(char str[], int length)
{
    printf("input: |%s|\n", str);
    int spacecount = 0, index;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            spacecount++;
        }
    }
    index = length + spacecount * 2;
    str[index] = '\0';
    for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (str[j] == ' ')
        {
            str[index - 1] = '0';
            str[index - 2] = '2';
            str[index - 3] = '%';
            index = index - 3;
        }
        else
        {
            str[index - 1] = str[j];
            index--;
        }
    }
    printf("output: |%s|\n", str);
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int len;
    printf("Enter the string : ");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    len = strlen(str);
    if (len > 0 && str[len-1] == '\n') str[--len] = '\0';
    URL(str, len);
}
```

Input:

```
Mr John Smith
```

note: With 5 extra spaces after Smith

Output:

```
input: |Mr John Smith     |
output: |Mr%20John%20Smith%20%20%20%20%20|
```

Comment: In solution, you are assuming that len is calculated by user but the input of length is given by user. Input : |Mr John Smith    |, 13 Output: |Mr%20John%20Smith|. Here I included extra four spaces after input "Smith", which makes the actual count of string to 17.

Comment: Also, if edited the program using ```fgets(str, 100, stdin)```, the ouput is "This%20is%20JohnS".

Comment: @Madhumitha If you prefer to take the length as user input, it doesn't change much - as long as the input is correct

Comment: I agree. Anyways, it works. Thanks for suggestion fgets().

Answer (score 2):

Besides using `fgets`, as proposed by @4386427, you can also use `scanf` with the specifier `%[^\n]` (matches anything that isn't a `\n`) to read an entire line, like this:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", str);
```

And for safety, when dealing with strings you should always limit the number of characters that can be read so that it doesn't exceed the length of the array `str`, by doing:

```
scanf(" %99[^\n]", str);
```

So your `main` could be:

```
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int len;
    printf("Enter the string : ");
    scanf(" %99[^\n]", str);
    for (int c=getchar(); c!='\n' && c!=EOF; c=getchar());
    len = strlen(str);
    URL(str, len);
}
```